# Can a lambda expression be applied to a query against a different object?

Tags: c#, linq

Sometimes it's nice to be able to store lambda expressions somewhere that mean something in your business logic, for example

```
Expression<Func<Supplier,bool>> SupplierHasHighRating = x => x.Rating > 90;
```

This is like a lite form of the Specification Pattern. So you can do this:

```
var highRatedSuppliers = someQueryableOfSuppliers.Where(SupplierHasHighRating);
```

What I'd like to know if there is a way I can reuse the lambda in a query against a different object which is related to Supplier:

```
var productsOfHighRatedSuppliers = someQueryableOfProducts.Where(x => x.Supplier.Rating > 90);
```

Can I reuse the lambda here somehow?

*Edit*: If you believe the answer is yes, can you show how you would do it in terms of the above example?

Comment: Yes. You can do almost anything with expressions, but much of it isn't straight forward to most programmers.

Comment: You could do this transparently by making an interface called ISupplierRating that requires a SupplierRating property or a GetSupplierRating method. Then apply the interface to both types. Finally use the  interface in your stored Expression.

Comment: @N-ate Thanks, I've edited the question above in response to your answer.

Comment: Another way you can do this is to make your expression use object and then it can apply to any collection. Inside the lambda do type checking. I personally dislike type checking objects, because it means you've lost design-time type checking.

Comment: I'd like to be able to use the result in a database query too. I assume the type checking would rule that out...

Comment: It wouldn't rule it out, but type checking is terrible, because if you make a mistake you won't know until runtime.

Answer (score -1):

As people have pointed out: It is absolutely possible to do with expressions. *However*, in most realistic scenarios, the time it would take to create such functionality, would make it unfeasible. Taking all factors into account, for instance; performance might be an issue.

Creating an expression visitor takes time, dynamic expressions are *hard*, and if you aren't familiar with them, you're likely killing a few good hours before you get any actual work done. It's just … very unintuitive, if you've never tried it before.

There are other ways around this though; one approach is to simply use inheritance.

For instance, create a `IRateable`, which simply only exposes the property `Rating`. Then simply inherit it where needed.

As in your example:

```
public class Supplier : IRateable
{
  public int Rating { get; set; }
}

public class Product : IRateable
{
  // Get's the suppliers rating, tho, is this what you wanted?
  public int Rating => Supplier.Rating;

  public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}
```